# Search all sites - What order do the results appear in? Can this be changed?

Tags: support, search, stackexchange.com

I searched using the "Search all sites" box.

My search term happened to be "delivery address"

I can detect no order in the results.

They are not in order of:

. date

. site

. alphabet (neither title nor content)

. tag

**Question**

There are thousands of results - I can't read through them all.

What order are they in?

Can I modify that order?

EDIT

Failing a general solution I'll throw out a specific one. I saw a question somewhere asking something like "Should I give my delivery address to a stranger".  Can anyone tell me which SE this is likely to be?

Comment: I expect there is no explicit order set and it is left to the used datastore (I expect Elastic Search here) to return results in whatever order it dreams up. Note that this order isn't guaranteed to be stable, so it can serve the results differently on the same search request. We don't have control over the order of the results

Comment: Thanks - Specifically I want to find a recent question (I can't remember where it was) that I later thought of an answer to. I'll modify my question to make it very specific.

Comment: @rene Unless something’s changed recently, the global search is just a custom Google search.

Comment: @NobodyNada yes, it changed. It's using internal SE search engine now.

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately the order can't be changed and it is unspecified what the order is. (When I add a created: search option the order becomes newest first but that is likely a coincidence, not a feature)

You can however use the [advanced search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) options

> [`"delivery address" is:q -[shop] -[php] created:10d..`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22delivery+address%22+is%3Aq+-%5Bshop%5D+-%5Bphp%5D+created%3A10d..)

to limit the results from across all sites to a manageable number that you can handle/filter/visit.

The specific question you're looking for is

[A stranger asks for my delivery address, how much information should I give?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/198067/a-stranger-asks-for-my-delivery-address-how-much-information-should-i-give)

which is found on Security.SE.

Comment: Thanks for both the general and the specific answers. It wasn't 'newest first' when I did the search. I think the first one was from 2015. However your other answers are invaluable.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK yeah, I just verified, order is undefined and depends on options used among other things.

Comment: Isn't it still HNQ? (which makes it easier to find ;))